# Not able to return authResponse from auth0-js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, auth0

I'm trying to implement an login mechanize and not able to return a value from the callback function. I'm using this npm package: [auth0-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auth0-js). There's two files in my setup.
The first one is authService.js where I have my login logic:

```
import auth0 from "auth0-js";

function initializeAuth0Client(domain, redirectUri, clientID) {
  return new auth0.WebAuth({
    domain: "{YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN}",
    clientID: "{YOUR_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}",
  });
}

function handleLogin(client, user) {
  return client.login(
    {
      realm,
      username,
      password,
    },
    (err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult) {
        return authResult;
      }
    }
  );
}

module.exports = {
  handleLogin,
  initializeAuth0Client,
};
```

The second one: index.js

```
import { handleLogin, initializeAuth0Client } from "authService";


const auth0Client = initializeAuth0Client(domain, redirectUri, clientID);
const authResponse = handleLogin(auth0Client, user);
console.log(authResponse) // undefined
```

I tried returning the value from the callback, as well as assigning the result to a local variable inside the function and returning that one, but none of those ways actually return the response. I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/11519084), but it didn't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following snippet, both lines will always try to run at the same time.

```js
const authResponse = handleLogin(auth0Client, user);
console.log(authResponse) // undefined
```

`console.log(authResponse)` is not going to wait for `handleLogin` to finish and return `authResult`

`authResult` is only available inside of the callback

```js
function handleLogin(client, user) {
  return client.login(
    {
      realm,
      username,
      password,
    },
    (err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult) {
        console.log(authResponse) // works!
        return authResult;
      }
    }
  );
}
```

If you want your code synchronously, or have `handleLogin(auth0Client, user);` resolve before having the rest of the code run, you can turn `handleLogin` into a function that returns a Promise that resolves with the `authResponse`. This will cause `console.log(authResponse)` to wait for `handleLogin(auth0Client, user);`.

```js
function handleLogin(client, user) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.login(
      {
        realm,
        username,
        password,
      },
      (err, authResult) => {
        if (authResult) {
          resolve(authResult);
        }
      }
    }
  );
}
```

```js
const auth0Client = initializeAuth0Client(domain, redirectUri, clientID);
const authResponse = await handleLogin(auth0Client, user);
console.log(authResponse) // works!
```

If you are doing this in Node, you have to make sure that you call this in an `async` function. Placing it inside a wrapper function should suffice

```js
async function auth() {
  const auth0Client = initializeAuth0Client(domain, redirectUri, clientID);
  const authResponse = handleLogin(auth0Client, user);
  console.log(authResponse) // works!
}

auth()
```